# Tests failed when codecept run with report parameter

Tags: yii2, codeception

I installed yii2 basic template project. I did not change anything in source code. When I run default tests by `codecept run` command, all tests passed. When I run codecept with parameter `--report`, functional tests failed for submit login and submit contact form cest.
Did anyone have such a problem?

My env: Yii 2.0.12, PHP 7.1.2, Codeception 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Codeception doesn't seem to have much documentation about the parameter `--report`, but it seems like you have to specify a custom reporter to use. Otherwise, you can use --html, --xml, etc for step by step reports

http://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted#Reports